# calling function from jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

I've seen a few similar questions to this, but have been unable to apply what i've learned from them on my project.

I'm using the tablesorter jquery plugin and it's pagination plugin, by default this does not have numbered page links so I am trying to add those in, the plugin code is as follows

```
(function($) {
    $.extend({
        tablesorterPager: new function() {

            function updatePageDisplay(c) {
                var s = $(c.cssPageDisplay,c.container).val((c.page+1) + c.seperator + c.totalPages);   
            }

            function setPageSize(table,size) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.size = size;
                c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);
                c.pagerPositionSet = false;
                moveToPage(table);
                fixPosition(table);
            }

            function fixPosition(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                if(!c.pagerPositionSet && c.positionFixed) {
                    var c = table.config, o = $(table);
                    if(o.offset) {
                        c.container.css({
                            top: o.offset().top + o.height() + 'px',
                            position: 'absolute'
                        });
                    }
                    c.pagerPositionSet = true;
                }
            }

            function moveToFirstPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page = 0;
                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function moveToLastPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function moveToNextPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page++;
                if(c.page >= (c.totalPages-1)) {
                    c.page = (c.totalPages-1);
                }
                moveToPage(table);
                console.log(table);
            }

            function moveToPrevPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page--;
                if(c.page <= 0) {
                    c.page = 0;
                }
                moveToPage(table);
            }


            function moveToPage(table) {
                var c = table.config;
                if(c.page < 0 || c.page > (c.totalPages-1)) {
                    c.page = 0;
                }

                renderTable(table,c.rowsCopy);
            }

            function gotoPage(table, newpage) {
                var c = table.config;
                c.page = newpage;

                moveToPage(table);
            }

            function renderTable(table,rows) {

                var c = table.config;
                var l = rows.length;
                var s = (c.page * c.size);
                var e = (s + c.size);
                if(e > rows.length ) {
                    e = rows.length;
                }


                var tableBody = $(table.tBodies[0]);

                // clear the table body

                $.tablesorter.clearTableBody(table);

                for(var i = s; i < e; i++) {

                    //tableBody.append(rows[i]);

                    var o = rows[i];
                    var l = o.length;
                    for(var j=0; j < l; j++) {

                        tableBody[0].appendChild(o[j]);

                    }
                }

                fixPosition(table,tableBody);

                $(table).trigger("applyWidgets");

                if( c.page >= c.totalPages ) {
                    moveToLastPage(table);
                }

                updatePageDisplay(c);
            }

            this.appender = function(table,rows) {

                var c = table.config;

                c.rowsCopy = rows;
                c.totalRows = rows.length;
                c.totalPages = Math.ceil(c.totalRows / c.size);

                renderTable(table,rows);
            };

            this.defaults = {
                size: 10,
                offset: 0,
                page: 0,
                totalRows: 0,
                totalPages: 0,
                container: null,
                cssNext: '.next',
                cssPrev: '.prev',
                cssFirst: '.first',
                cssThree: '.three',
                cssLast: '.last',
                cssPageDisplay: '.pagedisplay',
                cssPageSize: '.pagesize',
                seperator: "/",
                positionFixed: true,
                appender: this.appender
            };

            this.construct = function(settings) {

                return this.each(function() {   

                    config = $.extend(this.config, $.tablesorterPager.defaults, settings);

                    var table = this, pager = config.container;

                    $(this).trigger("appendCache");

                    config.size = parseInt($(".pagesize",pager).val());

                    $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToFirstPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssThree,pager).click(function() {
                        gotoPage(table, 4);
                        return false;
                        console.log('triggered');
                    });
                    $(config.cssFirst,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToFirstPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssNext,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToNextPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssPrev,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToPrevPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssLast,pager).click(function() {
                        moveToLastPage(table);
                        return false;
                    });
                    $(config.cssPageSize,pager).change(function() {
                        setPageSize(table,parseInt($(this).val()));
                        return false;
                    });
                });
            };

        }
    });
    // extend plugin scope
    $.fn.extend({
        tablesorterPager: $.tablesorterPager.construct
    });

})(jQuery);
```

I have added the following function

```
function gotoPage(table, newpage) {
                    var c = table.config;
                    c.page = newpage;

                    moveToPage(table);
                }
```

and wish to call it in the following way

```
onclick="gotoPage(table, '.$counter.'); return false;"
```

the above is generated in a php loop.

the below code is how I call the function

```
$("table") 
    .tablesorter({widthFixed: true, widgets: ['zebra']}) 
    .tablesorterPager({container: $("#pager")}); 
    var table = document.getElementById("page");
```

if anyone could assist in how to call the gotoPage function in my onclick it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered using the tablesorter pagination plugin?  http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-pager.html

Comment: this is said plugin, the functionality is a little limited and i'm trying to expand on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to modify from the inside, it would be simpler

remove the onclick and then add a handler inside the plugin code to have access to the private functions

```
$('.pagelink').on('click',function(){
 var newpage = $(this).attr('href').replace('#',''); //suppose that href="#'.$counter.'"
 var table = $('#table').get(0);
 gotoPage(table, newpage);
});
```